# Use javascript with the custom view policies in Azure AD B2C

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any possibility or trick to enable the use of our javascript for the sign-up policy when using custom views?

The error messages for each field appear from too many events (for the email field the error message is shown when typing the text...) and it's quite disturbing for the end-user...

Other point,the type for the email input field is type="text", no problem for a webapp but if we use it in a mobile application it doesn't block the autocompletion so the input for the user is quite difficult...

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Updated on 2018-11***

<s>At this point, Azure AD B2C does not support custom javascript on any of it's pages.</s>

This is currently <s>under development</s> *in preview* and you can express your interest and track it's progress by voting for the UserVoice entry in the Azure AD B2C UserVoice forum:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br

From the [Azure AD B2C Javascript sample documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples) you can achieve this by adding the `<ScriptExecution>` element to your custom policies as follows:

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPassword" />
  <UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
  </UserJourneyBehaviors>
  ...
</RelyingParty>
```

Comment: In Microsoft Ignite, Javascript-enabled custom policies were shown. See the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGWGO00sznc

How can we get access to the preview functionality of enabling Javascript?

Comment: This is currently available for custom policies, you can find the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples